# HTML/Javascript for Chrome Extension not quite working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make a chrome extension. My code works fine when I run it as a normal html page, but when I use browser action, my enable/disable button doesn't work. It doesn't do anything when I press enable (Which it should switch to disable). Was wondering if there is something I don't know about like permissions or something. I haven't set any permissions in my json page but I didn't think it was the problem. Was wondering if you guys can take a look and see what I'm missing. Here's my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nosidebar.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function enableBtn(){
                document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = "";
                return false;
            }

            function disableBtn(){
                document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "";
                return false;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton1" title="Click to disable" id="btn1" style="display:;" onclick="enableBtn(); return false;">Enabled</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton2" title="Click to enable" id="btn2" style="display:none;" onclick="disableBtn(); return false;">Disabled</a>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        You must refresh the page for the change to take effect.
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Thanks to @duskwuff I have fixed my problem. I created a separate js file and used the following code.**

```
function enableBtn(){
    document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = "";
    return false;
}

function disableBtn(){
    document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "";
    return false;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", enableBtn);
    document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", disableBtn);
});
```

Comment: Clarify where is that. Popup? Content?

Comment: @ZigMandel Sorry, it's the popup page. I think duskwuff answered my question but I'll need to try it out sometime today when I'm free.

Comment: @Ben It is highly recommended that you post your solution as (another) answer, _not_ edited into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML pages used as part of Google Chrome extensions always have a Content Security Policy set which prohibits inline scripts, both in attributes (e.g. `onclick`) and inline `<script>` tags. You will need to define these scripts in a separate Javascript file and bind event handlers in that script, e.g.

```
<script src="nosidebar.js"></script>
```

and in that file:

```
function enableBtn() { ... }
function disableBtn() { ... }

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", enableBtn);
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", disableBtn);
```

For more information on Content Security Policy and how it relates to Chrome extensions, please refer to:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy